# Pasar de pagina con boton paginas web

Tags: php, html, sql, css, sql-server

Hola necesito enviar el resultado de una consulta en un boton para otra pagina "prueba.php".
Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora.

```
$stmt = $conn->query($query);

$registros = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

     ?>

     <h1 class="text-center"> Vista Macroprocesses </h1>
     <div class="container" >

  <?php foreach ($registros as $fila) :

     if( $fila->GN_RED!="0"){
       echo '<button type="botton" class="botonred" href="/prueba.php">';
       echo $fila->CIDSLB_MP;
       echo " : ";
       echo $fila->GN_RED;
     echo '</button>';
   }else {}
```

La variable a enviar es $registros  la quiero enviar en el boton y estoy tratando de usar href para enviar esto a prueba pero no lo detecta, no pasa de pagina.

Comment: He respondido un par de tus preguntas y la verdad se hace difícil si es que no tienes conocimientos básicos. Te recomiendo estudiar sobre envíos `POST` y `GET` y los `querystring`, luego sobre las etiquetas `<form>`,  `type="submit"` y `<a>`

Comment: Usa un formulario y listo